# GWT Warning: "Call to Enum method toString when enum obfuscation is enabled"

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, enums

I use GWT 2.6 with the option:

```
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.enum.obfuscate.names" value="true" />
```

When I compile I get the following warning.

```
[WARN] Call to Enum method valueOf when enum obfuscation is enabled: Someclass
Replacing Enum.name method :  com/google/gwt/emul/java/lang/Enum.java:115
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Why you want to enable `obfuscate`?

Comment: @Braj Because it reduces the code size.

Answer (score 0):

When using enums in GWT, it is a good practice to not rely on enum's default methods like toString, name, valueOf.

If you want to provide a public access the enum's instance name, or you want to provide a factory method for retrieving a enum instance you would better create custom methods.

Consider the following example:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    FIRST("First"), SECOND("Second");

    // MyEnum factory method
    public static MyEnum of(String name) {
        switch (name) {
            case "First": return FIRST;
            case "Second": return SECOND;
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    private final String name;

    private MyEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```